# Using a Template to Expose a Private Typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have a class that contains a private typedef and several member
functions:

```
class Foo
{
private:
  typedef std::blahblah FooPart;
  FooPart m_fooPart;
  ...
public:
  int someFn1();
  int someFn2();
};
```

Several member functions need to use m_fooPart in a similar way, so I
want to put that in a function. I put helper functions in the anonymous
namespace whenever I can, but in this case, they need to know what
FooPart is. So, I've done this:

```
namespace
{
  template <typename T>
  int helperFn(const T& foopart, int index)
  {
    ...
    return foopart.fn(index);
  }
}

int Foo::someFn1()
{
  ...
  return helperFn(m_fooPart, ix);       
}
```

By forcing the compiler to produce the FooPart type, am I still in the
land of well-defined behavior? Is there a more elegant way of
accomplishing this that doesn't increase the size of Foo or make public
what is now private?

Comment: Why not make the helper function a private member of `Foo`? What do you perceive to be lost by taking this approach?

Comment: To be precise, the template will *not* expose the `typedef` but rather make the compiler resolve the type at the place of call.

Comment: @dribeas, thanks. It just seemed a bit odd that the type could be resolved implicitly (by the compiler), but not explicitly (by me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that approach produces well-defined, standards-compliant behavior.

That said, adding member functions to a class does not increase the size of a class (assuming you mean the result of the `sizeof` operator), so I'm not sure what drawback you perceive in just making the helper function a private member of `Foo`.

Comment: I guess the _size_ here means "number of characters in the .h file"

Comment: @anatolyg : Maybe, but I hope not -- that's a very silly metric.

Comment: I said "size", but I really should have said "complexity". It's mostly about keeping the class declaration as simple as possible.

Comment: @criddell : That being the case, try adding a implementation class as a friend of `Foo`, and putting all helper functions inside of that. That way, only 1 line is added to `Foo` itself, and the helper functions will have access to the private typedef.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: make the typedef public.

That will leak a minor detail of implementation (the actual internal type), but because it is typedefed you can redefine it at any time and it should be fine.

A little less simple: befriend the helper function, providing access to your internal type.

The problem with this second approach is that you are not only granting access to the typedef, but also to all the private parts of your class, and that might not be the best idea. At any rate, since this is an internal helper function, it is under your own control, and it should be fine. (Now that I think of it, you might want to declare the function in a named namespace, for the `friend` declaration to succeed)

Even less simple: Create a separate typedef inside the implementation file, and ensure that they are synchronized.

You can ensure that the types are the same with a small bit of metaprogramming, with a `same_type<T,U>` template that will provide a `true` value if the two types are the same and false otherwise. A static assert will trigger an error if the typedef changes in only one place

Back to simple again: provide the typedef or use the type directly without the static assert.

You are calling a function (this should not be a template as in your code) and passing a reference. If the typedef changes in the class, the call will fail and the compiler will tell you.

I would go for the last option, while it may look a little rough and less *delicate* than the others, the fact is that this is only an implementation detail that is not used by others, you are under full control of the code and well, simple is better.

**EDIT**, after the comment.

I started writing this as a comment, but it became too long, so I am adding it to the answer.

There is nothing wrong in that solution by itself, other than you are making a function generic unnecessarily and some error messages in the future might not be as simple as they could be with a non-generic signature. Note that the `template` will *not* expose the `typedef` (as the question title suggests) but rather it will make the compiler *infer* the type at the place of call.

If you change the `typedef`, instead of getting an error saying that the arguments to `helperFn` cannot be matched against the existing function, the type will be inferred and the function matched, but you will get an error deeper in `helperFn` if you use a property of the type that is no longer present. Or worse, you might not even get an error if it is the semantics of the type that have changed.

Consider that the typedef is of a `std::list<X>`, and that in the function you are iterating over it with this simple correct for loop:

```
for (typename T::iterator it=x.begin(), end=x.end(); it != end; ) {
   if ( condition(*it) ) 
      it = x.erase(it); 
   else 
      ++it; 
}
```

Can you catch the effect that changing the typedef to `std::vector<X>` will have? The compiler cannot even if the code is now incorrect. Whether writing the for loop like that is a good idea, or why is it not just using the *erase-remove* idiom are different issues (as a matter of fact the previous loop is *arguably better* than *erase-remove* for a list), the concrete situation is that the semantics have changed, and because the type is syntactically *compatible* with the previous one the compiler will not notice that the code is wrong, it will not point you to that function and chances are that you will not review/rewrite it.

Comment: First, what's wrong with a function being a template? Secondly, good point about being notified by the compiler if my typedef changes. I'm starting to think your last option is the way to go as well (@anatolyg gave me the same advice).

Comment: @criddell: I have updated the answer with some specific comments on what the issues with your approach might be.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the idea of **generic programming** - do stuff with a part of `Foo` without knowing its type.
A more "traditional" (strongly-typed, boring, readable, code-duplicating - you name it) way would be to mention the type explicitly:

```
int helperFn(const std::blahblah& foopart, int index)
{
    ...
    return foopart.fn(index);
}
```

Comment: The actual type is much, much longer. I used a typedef to avoid code duplication (as you mentioned) and to give a descriptive name to the type.